# How call date_trunc function in amazon Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to select the [date_trunc](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html) value:

```
select date_trunc(HOUR, current_date - interval '1' hour);
```

OR

```
select date_trunc(HOUR, current_date);
```

And got error:

```
[42703] ERROR: column "hour" does not exist Позиция: 19
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question borders on just being a typo, but from what I could find the date/time unit first parameter to `date_trunc` needs to be in single quotes:

```
select date_trunc('HOUR', current_date - interval '1' hour);
OR
select date_trunc('HOUR', current_date);
```

This answer might be worth posting as [Presto's own documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html) does not give any actual examples of how to use `date_trunc`.